# photo upload limit on carrier wave undefined method for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave as my photo albums, and I am trying to setup so I can prevent users from only being able to upload maximum 5 photos to their gallery. However I am getting back a "undefined method `user'" error when clicking on the Upload Photo button with page title "NoMethodError in PhotosController#create"

Photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :gallery_id, :name, :image, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    LIMIT = 5

    validate do |record|
      record.validate_photo_quota
    end

    def validate_photo_quota
      return unless self.user
      if self.user.photos(:reload).count >= LIMIT
        errors.add(:base, :exceeded_quota)
      end
    end
end
```

Photos_controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:gallery_id => params[:gallery_id])
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end
end
```

I thought I previously had user defined unless it has to be done for every controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `self.user` into the `Photo` model. The keyword `self` in that case represent an instance of `photo`. By your definition, a `photo` belongs to a `gallery` and therefore, there is no `user` to be called from photo.

If a `gallery` belongs to a user, then you should be able to call `self.gallery.user` to select the user owner of that photo.

---

You can also define a `has_many :through` association so as you can directly call the user from that photo, or retrive all the photos from that user.

This can be done following the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). In your case:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :galeries
  has_many :photos, :through => :galeries
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :through => :gallery
  belongs_to :gallery
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
end
```

Then you should be able to call `photo.user` and get the owner of the picture.

Comment: That does the same. I understand what you're saying though. I think what I need to do first is create a way so that a album belongs to User A, etc. Right now I can just go to /galleries and view them all. I don't think any created gallery belongs to any particular user atm. Then once that is setup I should be able to better def the restriction of how many photos a user can upload and use your method. That's what I think at least as I'm new to Rails.

Comment: Yup, if you want a gallery to belong to a user, you should explicit this association. This can be done the same way you did so as a picture belongs to a gallery. However, if you want a user to have only one gallery, then the relationship should be has_one instead of has_many.